# Grafana doesnt display microsecond time series sometimes

Tags: grafana, azure-data-explorer

I am using KQL to pull data from ADX to Grafana, in ADX it is showing up entire time (with microseconds) but grafana has some issues with display

ADX

[image: ADX output]

Grafana

[image: Grafana]

But if I zoom out a little it starts working

[image: Grafana output]

Anyone here knows how to fix this issue from grafana display side?

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/48917) seems to be about this exact problem.

Comment: This looks like a bug. Please open an issue for Grafana - https://github.com/grafana/azure-data-explorer-datasource/issues